# How to restrict multiple notification from EstimoteSDK in iOS / Swift3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uilocalnotification, ibeacon, estimote

I implemented Estimote SDK and added beacon ranging/scanning delegate method. Now, I want to trigger local notification when device just enter in beacon region. Here I'm facing problem with local notification.
When I enter in beacon region, I'm getting notification which is fine but it repeats multiple times after random interval. I'm getting local notification more than once.

Second thing is, Is there any way to clear triggered notification from notification area. Because I want to show only 1 notification at a time. So, When it triggers local notification, It should clear exist notification from notification area, if there is any already.

I tried with *cancelLocalNotification* and *cancelAllLocalNotifications* but notifications are not being removed.

Comment: Please share your code to see what you might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my implementation of code:

```
    beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
    beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = true
    self.beaconManager.delegate = self
    self.beaconManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.beaconManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)

func beaconManager(_ manager: Any, didEnter region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    if isAuthenticated == nil {
        return
    }

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "You are in beacon range."
    notification.fireDate = Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2)
    notification.userInfo = ["enterInBeaconRange":true]
    UIApplication.shared.presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)

}
```

Now If I'm setting "cancelAllLocalNotifications" method before notification, it's not clearing all previous notification from notification centre.

Comment: You can't cancel the notifications which are already triggered. You can do it for the scheduled ones.

Comment: Is it possible with new framework **UNUserNotificationCenter** ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, you can use `removeAllDeliveredNotification()` to clear the previous notification. The best way is used to have the identifier for the delivered notification and then `removeDeliveredNotifications("PREVIOUSLY_DEVLIVERED_NOTIFICATION_ID")`.

Comment: UNUserNotificationCenter framework handles itself, what you need to do is just set identifier for notification. So when application fires notification with same id, it'll replace existing one. :) Thanks. :)